# iOS: NSNumberFormatter from local currency to double

Tags: ios, localization, nsnumberformatter

I've got a string with currency having the format of the local currency.
For example 
10000 Danish kroner will be (10.000,00)
When cast to double value it just read it 10.
I tried this snippet

```
NSString * locale ;
    if(locale == nil || [locale isEqualToString:@""]){
        locale = @"da_DK";
    }
   NSLocale *priceLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:locale] ;
[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:actualCash locale:priceLocale].doubleValue
```

But it didn't work

any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` directly:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"da_DK"];
NSNumber* result = [formatter numberFromString:@"10.000,00"];
```